# Manifest Merger Error when adding Vokaturi

Tags: android

I'm making a Mobile and Wear application. However, for the wear build.gradle I'm getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault) from AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-59
>       is also present at [:OpenVokaturi-3-0-android:] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-40 value=(@style/AppTheme).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-36:19 to override.
>   "

This is the Mobile.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'                               
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "chun.emotionsensor"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
wearApp project(':wear')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
compile(name: 'OpenVokaturi-3-0-android', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
```

This is the wear.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "chun.emotionsensor"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:wear:26.1.0'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
compile(name: 'OpenVokaturi-3-0-android', ext: 'aar')

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **OpenVokaturi** library that you have included in your build has set a theme value that conflicts with the theme of your application.

It is possible to overrride this conflicting theme by adding the following to your manifest, AndroidManifest.xml, and building your application again:

```
tools:replace="android:theme"
```

Comment: I've tried that suggestion, however, in doing so it leads to more errors, as shown in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj4aJ.png

Comment: Don't include links to images of code errors, rather format it properly and include it in the question.